# Understanding the event loop and partitioning in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've read this nice doc guide: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/dont-block-the-event-loop/

And in some part of that article it's being said regarding to complex calculations without blocking the Event Loop:

> Suppose you want
> to do complex calculations in JavaScript without blocking the Event
> Loop. You have two options: partitioning or offloading. You could
> partition your calculations so that each runs on the Event Loop but
> regularly yields (gives turns to) other pending events.

And they gave as an example this code example to calculate the avg of 0 + 1 + 2 + ... + n :

```js
function asyncAvg(n, avgCB) {
  // Save ongoing sum in JS closure.
  var sum = 0;
  function help(i, cb) {
    sum += i;
    if (i == n) {
      cb(sum);
      return;
    }

    // "Asynchronous recursion".
    // Schedule next operation asynchronously.
    setImmediate(help.bind(null, i+1, cb));
  }

  // Start the helper, with CB to call avgCB.
  help(1, function(sum){
      var avg = sum/n;
      avgCB(avg);
  });
}

asyncAvg(n, function(avg){
  console.log('avg of 1-n: ' + avg);
});
```

My questions are:

1. According to this doc link: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick

The `setImmediate` will be executed If the poll phase scripts have been scheduled by `setImmediate()`, then the event loop will end the poll phase and continue to the check phase to execute those scheduled scripts.

but if we are in the recursive step:

```js
function help(i, cb) {
    sum += i;
    if (i == n) {
      cb(sum);
      return;
    }

    // "Asynchronous recursion".
    // Schedule next operation asynchronously.
    setImmediate(help.bind(null, i+1, cb));
  }
```

then the poll should be empty but the `setImmediate` command, and therefore it should keep running the recursive, so how would it give opportunity to other code to be executed meanwhile? in terms of event-loop scheduling.

2. Why for really big `n` there isn't `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` error, but if I change this line:

```js
setImmediate(help.bind(null, i+1, cb));
```

to this line:

```
help(i+1, cb);
```

then the error `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` pops up. I mean, using the `setImmediate` should anyway keep the functions stack caused by the recursive, no?

Comment: Just a side note, FWIW: These days, offloading is a **lot** easier than the ways that article discusses, thanks to [worker threads](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder that's a nice insight! hopefully you could also help with the question itself :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> then the poll should be empty but the setImmediate command, and therefore it should keep running the recursive, so how would it give opportunity to other code to be executed meanwhile?

Because `setImmediate` schedules callbacks to happen just after the `poll` phase completes. Those callbacks are run during the `check` phase. Adding more callbacks during `check` schedules them, but doesn't cause them to run; that happens the next time the loop gets to the `poll` phase, sees there are pending callbacks, and enters the `check` phase.

> Why for really big n there isn't RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded error

Because the recursion isn't immediate, so it doesn't consume stack space. `setImmediate` just schedules a callback, it doesn't *call* the callback. Your code ends, releasing its stack resources, and the event loop continues. Later, the callback you scheduled via `setImmediate` gets run, briefly using a small bit of stack space.

In contrast, when you call `help` immediately, that's allocating a new stack frame, and if you use a big `n`, you allocate too many stack frames and run out of stack.